# Prevent Internet Explorer from saving files with the "T" attribute set

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer, dfs

Okay, here's the issue at hand - Internet Explorer is behaving badly (as in the opposite of Google Chrome and FireFox) and when users save an image to our file server, the temp bit is set, so DFS doesn't replicate the file. See this article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/406.dfsr-does-not-replicate-temporary-files.aspx

The workflow for the issue here is:

1. A staff member receives a file (usually an image) from Outlook or the web.
2. They open the file, it opens in Internet Explorer (version 8).
3. They save the file (ie, to their desktop). For some reason the temp attribute gets set.
4. They copy it to our file server (which is dfs'd).
5. Manager goes to check for it and it doesn't show up.
6. Blame I.T.

I did some glancing around on the web, but didn't find quite what I was after. Anyone have a suggestion as to a method that will stop Internet Explorer from marking these files as temporary, even when the user is saving the file to their desktop?

Solutions tried:

- Creating a task that runs the powershell fix for the temp file issue.
- Have the end user run the fix.
- Set default program for images to firefox.

Thanks in advance for anything that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Symantec Endpoint Protection?  This article suggests that the Outlook Auto-Protect plug-in may set the temporary attribute:

http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/sep-1104-outlook-auto-protect-sets-temporary-attribute-attachments-files-dont-replicate-dfsr

*"I just discovered an issue with Symantec Endpoint Protection 11.0.4 causes issues with DFSR Replication.*

*"Apparently Outlook Auto-Protect causes email attachments that are saved to have the hidden "Temporary File" attribute set.  DFSR doesn't replicate files with the temporary file attribute by design.   Because of this, any user who saved a file from Outlook to our file servers was unable to replicate those files between offices."*

If so, perhaps it is resolved in a newer version?

Comment: Thanks for this information - we are using Symantec Endpoint Protection, however we do not have any plugins installed or enabled. I have upgraded Internet Explorer, and that does seem to a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with step 2. Can they try to save the image directly from Outlook instead of opening it up in IE?

Keep in mind that Outlook uses a custom, 'secure' temporary directory when you open files from items. It would make sense that Outlook is setting the temp bit on the files when creating them, as from Outlook's point of view, they are temporary. IE is dutifully creating a copy of the file, probably with the temp bit set entirely unintentionally.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but it is super hard to retrain users. I'm more likely to be fired. As it was explained to me, "They need to open the file to verify it, and to know the where to place the file and what to name the file". So in short, changing the business process is not an ideal solution, and the problem still has the possibility to occur.

As I mention in Greg Askew's post, upgrading Internet Explorer seemed to fix my issue.